# Jumping to a line and reading it

Tags: java, file, io

I have to work with big files (many GB) and need quick lookups to retrieve specific lines on request.

The idea has been to maintain a mapping:

```
some_key -> byte_location
```

Where the byte location represents where in the file the line starts.

Edit: the question changed a little bit:

First I used:

```
FileInputStream stream = new FileInputStream(file);
BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(stream));
FileChannel channel = stream.getChannel();
```

I noticed that `FileChannel.position()` will not return the exact position where the reader is currently reading because it is a "buffered" reader. It reads chunks of a given size (16k here) so what I get from the FileChannel is a multiple of 16k, and not the exact position where the reader is actually reading.

PS: the file is in UTF-8

Comment: What is the encoding of your file ?

Comment: What is the question about? How to jump to a given position in the input stream? `in.skip(pos);`. Or how to find the desired position to jump to read the whole line, and not a part?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would have tried something like this:

```
    RandomAccessFile raf = new RandomAccessFile(file);
    ...
    raf.seek(position);
    raf.readLine();
    ...
```

The problem is that [`readLine()`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/RandomAccessFile.html#readLine%28%29) turns each byte into a character with the top 8 bits zero.  That's fine if your file is ASCII or Latin-1, but problematic for UTF-8.

However, if you are prepare to use RandomAccessFile to write the file, you can use [`readUTF()`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/RandomAccessFile.html#readUTF%28%29) and [`writeUTF()`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/RandomAccessFile.html#writeUTF%28%29) to read and write "lines" encoded as modified UTF-8 Strings.

**FOLLOWUP**

> dammit ...utf-8 characters are screwed

Yea ... see above.

Another idea for coping with UTF-8 with `RandomAccessFile`:

1. seek to desired position,
2. use `readFully(byte[])` method to read a bunch of bytes into a `byte[]`,
3. locate `pos` == position of the end of line in the buffer,
4. if not found, read more bytes, concatenate and go to step 2.
5. if found, use `new String(bytes, 0, pos, UTF-8)` to convert to a Java String.

This is more cumbersome than using `readLine()`, but it should be faster than using `FileInputStream` and `skip()` when reading multiple lines from the files in random order.

Comment: dammit ...utf-8 characters are screwed

Answer (score 3):

Any reason not to create a `FileInputStream`, call `stream.skip(pos)` and then create an `InputStreamReader` around that, and a `BufferedReader` around the `InputStreamReader`?

Comment: the `InputStreamReader` was my missing link I was looking for. Thanks.

Comment: @arnaud: if you don't actually know where you want to read, it's hard to see how you can get round that... reading to a specific line without reading all the data is basically hard. Will your file stay fixed for a long time? If so, you could put some effort into reading the whole thing accurately and just remember the *exact* offsets.

Comment: the plan was to make a first sweep over all data, reading it line by line and storing some "check points": important lines and their position. Once this indexing is in memory and a request come, the aim is to jump to the nearest check point and make a quick lookup.

Comment: ...ah ...i guess the only way to do it would be to extend the class and store the position myself.